# using Jquery button unable to disable the button

Tags: javascript

Iam not able to disable the button using jquery. I tried all the possible options but it is not working. Iam able to access and display the other properties of button, but disabling is not working. Iam using Jquery 1.8 and browser IE 7. Below is the code. Please help me in this regard.

```
<input type="button" class="actionButton" style="display: inline;" onclick="addCompany();" id="addCompanyId" value="Add country1111">

function setParentCompany(comId) {
    $('#parentCompanyDomain').val(comId);

    /* var buttonObj = $("#addCompanyId");
    //alert("buttonObj"+ buttonObj[0].id);
    buttonObj.setAttribute("disabled",true);
    //alert("button disabled value11122::"+buttonObj[0].attr('disabled')); */
    alert("id::"+$('#addCompanyId').attr("id"));
    alert("class::"+$('#addCompanyId').attr("class"));
    alert("value::"+$('#addCompanyId').attr("value"));
    alert("disable::"+$('#addCompanyId').attr("disabled"));

    $('#addCompanyId').attr("disabled",true);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#addCompanyId').prop("disabled",true)
```

true / false doesn't work with `attr()` so you should use `prop()`

If you have to use `attr()` then do the following

```
$('#addCompanyId').attr("disabled","disabled");
```

Comment: Hi i tried with all below options. but nothing was worked for me.                                                 $('#addCompanyId').attr("disabled","disabled");

$('#addCompanyId').prop("disabled",true);
$('#addCompanyId').prop("disabled","disabled");                                             Please help me to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#addCompanyId').attr("disabled", "disabled");//for jquery <1.6

                           or

        $('#addCompanyId').prop('disabled', true);//for jquery =>1.6
        }
```

This will work!!!

Comment: Hi i tried with all below options, but  nothing was worked for me.  $('#addCompanyId').attr("disabled","disabled"); $('#addCompanyId').prop("disabled",true); $('#addCompanyId').prop("disabled","disabled");

Comment: which jquery version are you using??

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
$('#addCompanyId').prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: Hi i tried with the all below options, but nothing is working for me.                                                                  $('#addCompanyId').attr("disabled","disabled");

$('#addCompanyId').prop("disabled",true);
$('#addCompanyId').prop("disabled","disabled");

Comment: @user1453851: I have checked my code in firefox and IE... It should work.. where did u try this?

Answer (score 0):

A combination of both of the above will do it:

```
$('#addCompanyId').prop('disabled','disabled')
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the below code:

```
$('#addCompanyId').attr("disabled",true);
```

Use the below code:

```
$('#addCompanyId').attr("disabled","disabled");
```

[Reference site](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/disable-enable-button-in-form).

Comment: Hi i tried with all below options. but nothing was worked for me. $('#addCompanyId').attr("disabled","disabled"); $('#addCompanyId').prop("disabled",true); $('#addCompanyId').prop("disabled","disabled"); Please help me to fix this problem.

Comment: @user1453851 Try by writing the code at first line of function means at the upper side in function. I think any other code is restricting in executing this.